# An acknowledgements page looks awesome

Tags: tikz-pgf, typewriter, text-decorations

How do I to make this acknowledgements page font  looks better?

Any brilliant idea, please ?

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{babel}

        \begin{document}
              \clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\par\vspace*{.35\textheight}{\centering Dedicated to my professor\par}
\\
          \centering
   \texttt{ It is with our deepest gratitude and warmest affection \\
        That we dedicate this thesis \\
        To our Professor Dr. X \\
    Who has been a constant source of Knowledge and inspiration.}

        \end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

could you please suggest me way to make this acknowledgements page nice looking??

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you mean by *academic*?

Comment: @ Johannes_B  my thesis in Mathematics that's why i said academic

Comment: Do you want to replace every latin letter p by a greek letter `\pi` to make it more mathematical?

Comment: This MWE reminds me of this :) http://i.stack.imgur.com/txnYc.jpg

Comment: It's not even an hour and there are two close votes. We need to cool a little down.

Comment: @percusse More importantly, the close votes were cast without anyone telling the OP what should be improved about his question. I think he should be given a chance to improve his question first. So, could you please be more specific about the design you are using for your thesis (surely not something as barren as `article`), and about what you want (should the thanks be on one page, should they be like a dedication, etc.)? You are the best judge as to what is "academic" or not (it depends on countries), so an example of something you would consider appropriate could be a good idea as well.

Comment: @ ienissei Thanks this is helping me to update my question

Comment: I'm still not quite understanding your question. You've posted code and an image. Do you want to know how to adapt the code so it creates something which looks like the image you posted? If so, can you tell us a bit more about your document setup? As @ienissei said, presumably you are not using `article` for a thesis and presumably you do not want to use `abstract` for the dedication? Also, which fonts are you using?

Comment: The was asking myself the same question. We need to know a little bit more about what you are trying to achieve and which resources are available (documentclass)

Comment: The texttt font is not very pretty. You would be better off using the standard font.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with your question;

1. You have an exceedingly subjective requirement that it must be beautiful. Well, for example, I don't find Comic Sans ugly (not an antonym of beautiful in this context!!) but if I use it here our experts will trace my IP and send drones to my address in order to exterminate me. But I like drones so here goes nothing;

   ```
   \documentclass{memoir}
   \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
   \usepackage{fontspec,pgfornament,background}
   \setmainfont{Comic Sans MS}

   \newenvironment{dedication}
     {\clearpage           % we want a new page
      \thispagestyle{empty}% no header and footer
      \vspace*{\stretch{1}}% some space at the top 
      \centering           % 
     }
     {\par % end the paragraph
      \vspace{\stretch{3}} % space at bottom is three times that at the top
      \clearpage           % finish off the page
     }

   \backgroundsetup{
   scale=1,
   opacity=1,
   angle=0,
   color=black,
   contents={%
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
   \node[anchor=north west](CNW)
   at (current page.north west) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm]{61}};
   \node[anchor=north east](CNE)
   at (current page.north east) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=v]{61}};
   \node[anchor=south west](CSW)
   at (current page.south west) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=h]{61}};
   \node[anchor=south east](CSE)
   at (current page.south east) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=c]{61}};
   \end{tikzpicture}%
     }
   }
   \begin{document}

   \begin{dedication}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[color=Maroon,
   every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
   %\draw[help lines] (-6,-6) grid (6,6);
   \node[minimum size=12cm](vecbox){};
   \node[anchor=north west] at (vecbox.north west)
   {\pgfornament[width=5cm]{61}};
   \node[anchor=north east] at (vecbox.north east)
   {\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=v]{61}};
   \node[anchor=south west] at (vecbox.south west)
   {\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=h]{61}};
   \node[anchor=south east] at (vecbox.south east)
   {\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=c]{61}};
   \node[align=center,text width=10cm] at (0,0) {
   It is with our deepest gratitude and warmest affection that we dedicate this thesis
   \vspace{2em}        

           to our Professor Dr. X

   \vspace{2em}
       who has been a constant source of Knowledge and inspiration.
   };
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{dedication}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   Well, fortunately, it will not compile unless you use LuaLaTeX, install comic sans fonts, install `pgfornament` package and run at least twice. I'm sure you agree with me that Comic Sans adds a personal touch....*meanwhile drone noise becomes unbearable*... What's that laser pointer on my screen?

   What I did here is first search for **dedication** on the site. And that would give you egreg's answer on [Dedication page in article class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102830/dedication-page-in-article-class) and then stole a few ideas from Gonzalo and Harish in [ornaments in pgfornament to be at the corners at every page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159597/ornaments-in-pgfornament-to-be-at-the-corners-at-every-page) because I know the wonderful package of Alain Matthes.
2. The other problem is that dedication is a personal thing. If you are serious about dedication, design something personal and try to achieve it. Whenever you are stuck with it, paste the incomplete code here and people here would jump on it. But right now you just want something to be **designed** for free (which is OK) and brilliant (which is not OK) to pay your respect to your professor.

Comment: @@percusse Thanks so much that's what i want

Comment: @Educ I don't think so but my pleasure :)

Comment: i have problem with compilation i already use LuaLaTeeX and i put the pakackge  pgfornament.sty on the same folder of my tex but doesn't work  i found the website of pgfornament  provide awesome exampls [here](http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/index.html)

Comment: @Educ On that page there is a pdf file that explains the installation.

Comment: Target locked. Send in the drones. `:)`